# PHP Undefined index, but var_dump says otherwise

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

I have a very odd problem, I have a user profile page I am building. I have a PDO function that gets a result set using the username of the requested user. However, when I have the array return I try to use the data from it I get an "undefined index" error. But what is odd is that when I var_dump the array I can see all of the values that are in it!

```
$_GET['name'] = (isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : '');
$req = $_GET['name'];
$info = array();
$info = getInfo($req);
echo($info['userid']);
var_dump($info);
```

the get info function gets the result set from PDO. For example, if I tried to use `$info['userid']` I get the error, but if I var dump I can see

```
["userid"]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "1"
```

**Update**
Here's the GetInfo function.

```
function getInfo($req){
$db = new database(DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
$rs = $db->query('SELECT name, username, level, userid FROM users WHERE username = ?')
    ->bind(1, $req)
    ->resultset();
return $rs;
}
```

The database is a bit long to post, if it would help I can post it.

Comment: Are you sure it's the `echo` call handing down the error? What does the function `getInfo()` do?

Comment: @Michael
The GetTnfo(); function user PDO to get a result set, then returns it.

Comment: @user1126921 Ok, but please post the function. I'm suspicious that the error may actually be happening in there.

Comment: Does the *undefined index* error point to the `echo` line or somewhere else? Also, you have a closing parenthesis without a matching opening one on line #1 above

Comment: @user1126921: why are you assigning `$_GET['name']` a value in your script?  Why are you altering `$_GET` at all?  You should not do this.  I have a feeling this is only the beginning of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Without the getInfo() source, my best guess is that the PDO query returns an object instead of an array, so please try to use echo $info->userid;

You can find more info about fetch modes [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).